# Filter Array in Array by date between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to filter a data-array of a LineChart by the from-date / to-date input of a user in TypeScript for my Angular App.
The data array has the following structure:

```
var multi = [
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "series": [
        {
            "date": new Date("2018-01-01T01:10:00Z"),
            "value": 44
        },...
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "series": [
        {
            "date": new Date("2018-01-01T01:10:00Z"),
            "value": 38
          },...
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "series": [
        {
            "date": new Date("2018-01-01T01:10:00Z"),
            "value": 33
          },...
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I now want to filter the items of the array by the criteria that the date inside is after a 'fromDate' and before a 'toDate'. I tried the following:

```
obj.forEach(data => {
            console.log(data.name);
            data.series = data.series.filter((item: any) => {
                item.date.getTime() >= fromDate.getTime() &&
                item.date.getTime() <= toDate.getTime();
            });
        });
```

the `obj[]` array has an empty `obj[i].series` array afterwards. Can anybody help me here? The iteration seems to be right since debugging gave me all the dates, also the true/False statements from the date comparing was right as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to `return` the compairing value, either explicit

```
data.series = data.series.filter((item: any) => {
    return item.date.getTime() >= fromDate.getTime() &&
           item.date.getTime() <= toDate.getTime();
});
```

or without the brackets, implicit.

```
data.series = data.series.filter((item: any) =>
    item.date.getTime() >= fromDate.getTime() && item.date.getTime() <= toDate.getTime()
);
```

Comment: To add to this, there is a difference between using brackets and not using them on arrow functions. When you use brackets, you're expected to write a full body of a function - including the `return` statement. When NOT using brackets, you're expected to write only the in-lined statement that is supposed to be returned by the arrow function. So, to solve this problem, either remove the brackets or include the `return` keyword.

Answer (score 6):

I had an issue with this when the end date was the same as the start date to solve this issue I had to set the time on the end date to 23.59

```
const start =  new Date().getTime()
const end=new Date()
end.setHours(23,59,59,999)
end.getTime()

return items.filter(item => {
   let date = new Date(item.created_at).getTime();
   return date >= start && date <= end;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let start = new Date(this.min);
let end   = new Date(this.max);

return items.filter(item => {
   let date = new Date(item.created_at);
   return date >= start && date <= end;
}
```