# How to get StartDate and EndData between Array of Dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of dates **array can be very large around 10,000 objects** like as

```
[{"date":"2019-01-23T11:01:50.719Z","lat":28.591072559026497,"lng":77.32183123723946},{"date":"2019-01-23T11:01:58.313Z","lat":28.591143596331815,"lng":77.32190503671627},{"date":"2019-01-23T11:04:13.272Z","lat":28.59104724711076,"lng":77.32189079414962},{"date":"2019-01-23T11:07:21.256Z","lat":28.591160550128887,"lng":77.32204036332226}]
```

I am trying to filter above Large Array by Date between **start and end date**. 
Since one date has many date with time. Like as

```
22/01/19 11:00, 22/01/19 12:00,22/01/19 1:00,22/01/19 2:00........... 24/01/19 1:00, 24/01/19 2:00,24/01/19 3:00 .......... 25/01/19 1:00
```

Suppose my start date is 22/01/19 and End date is 24/01/19. So array will be start from 22/01/19 2:00 (highest time) to 24/01/19 3:00. I am trying to create the logic but unable to do it. Kindly help me please.

Comment: what is start date and end date?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Unlike other pages StackOverflow is not a "give me free code" page. We will help you after you have shown minimal effort. To help you a bit I would have a look at the javascript '.filter()'  method. Also this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227286/filter-array-in-array-by-date-between-2-dates

Comment: You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter also if you don't want to make date objects of the dates then ISO 8601 date comparison is equivalent to a string comparison if the time zones are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for filter the data and compare data using moment for example:

```
const filteredDates = dates.filter(date => {
 const date = moment(date)
 const start = moment(start);
 const end = moment(end);
 if(date > start && date < end){
  return true;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here. Actually a one-liner on the process of filtering on its own.

```js
const data = [{
  "date": "2019-01-23T11:01:50.719Z",
  "lat": 28.591072559026497,
  "lng": 77.32183123723946
}, {
  "date": "2019-01-22T11:01:58.313Z",
  "lat": 28.591143596331815,
  "lng": 77.32190503671627
}, {
  "date": "2019-01-24T11:04:13.272Z",
  "lat": 28.59104724711076,
  "lng": 77.32189079414962
}, {
  "date": "2019-01-25T11:07:21.256Z",
  "lat": 28.591160550128887,
  "lng": 77.32204036332226
}]

let startDate = new Date("2019-01-22T02:00:00")
let endDate = new Date("2019-01-24T03:00:00")
let result = data.filter(d => new Date(d.date) >= startDate && new Date(d.date) <= endDate)
console.log(result)
```