# Filter array based on start and end date using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, date, filter

I have an array of data with start and end date which is being displayed in angular calendar. I would like to filter the array based on the start and end date.

```
0: {id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-06T09:00:13Z", end_date: "2019-11-11T14:00:13Z"}
1: {id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-04T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-07T07:12:09Z"}
2: {id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-04T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-07T07:03:21Z"}
3: {id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-26T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-27T07:03:21Z"}
4: {id: 66, start_date: "2019-11-04T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-07T07:12:09Z"}
5: {id: 66, start_date: "2019-11-05T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-12T07:03:21Z"}
```

If I am on day 2019-11-07 (I couldn't get the date from here for filter)
I want to build an array like this from above without using the 2019-11-07

```
0: {id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-06T09:00:13Z", end_date: "2019-11-11T14:00:13Z"}
1: {id: 66, start_date: "2019-11-04T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-07T07:12:09Z"}
```

The following is the filter i have written

```
data.forEach((item, index) => {
if (index !== data['results'].findIndex(i => i.id === item.id && 
new Date(i.start_date).toDateString() === new Date(item.start_date).toDateString() && 
new Date(i.end_date).toDateString() === new Date(item.end_date).toDateString())) {
data.splice(index, 1);
}                   
});
console.log(data);
```

If I am on 2019-11-07, i am not able to remove this item

```
0: {id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-06T09:00:13Z", end_date: "2019-11-11T14:00:13Z"}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why `.forEach()`, `.findIndex()` and `.splice()` and not a simple `.filter()`?

Comment: Converting a string into a date and then converting it back into a string to compare it against another string is at least strange...

Comment: Actually, I don't want to build an array. I just wanted to remove the unwanted items from array. For better understanding expected output shows there

Comment: please check [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227286/filter-array-in-array-by-date-between-2-dates)

Comment: Quote from your question: _"I want to build an array like this from above..."_

Comment: @SouravGolui Since I am using angular calendar and on page load I wanted to mark some counts on  calendar. So I am not able to get a specific date from there. So the filtering is a problem here

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` instead of `forEach`:

```
const filterDate = {
  start_date: "2019-11-07T09:00:13Z",
  end_date: "2019-11-07T09:00:13Z",
};

const filteredItems = data.filter((item, index) => item.start_date >= filterDate.start_date && item.end_date <= filterDate.end_date);
```

I'm not sure whether you really want to include only the specific date or all the items contained in the selected interval. This example assumes the latter.

Also you might not always have the filterDate object so you want to add specific logic to check that.

Comment: I have a calendar to mark the leaves of employees. So from calendar I have to see the count of employees leave on a particular day. On page load, I am getting data from api and I can filter the array with same start date and end date. However, someone might be taking leave on series of days and where the start and end date will be different. But the specific day include. This situation I wanted to implement here. Can you help me?

Comment: @JomolMJ here you should add start and end date query support to the API which will give you the filtered data instead of creating an overhead to the frontend.

What you do at the frontend is simply update the state with the API filtered data.

Comment: @MohdZeeshan, I want to mark the calendar with the count of persons on leave on page load. This is  the ui from client and I am not able to change it. any possibilities to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here what you need to is as per filter date selection:
`filterStartDate` time should `00:00:00` and `filterEndDate` time should be `23:59:59`...

secondly use below code...

```
let data = [
{id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-06T09:00:13Z", end_date: "2019-11-11T14:00:13Z"}
,{id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-04T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-07T07:12:09Z"}
,{id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-04T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-07T07:03:21Z"}
,{id: 86, start_date: "2019-11-26T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-27T07:03:21Z"}
,{id: 66, start_date: "2019-11-04T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-07T07:12:09Z"}
,{id: 66, start_date: "2019-11-05T18:30:00Z", end_date: "2019-11-12T07:03:21Z"}
]


const filterDate = {
  start_date: "2019-11-04T00:00:00Z",
  end_date: "2019-11-07T23:59:59Z",
};

const filteredItems = data.filter((item, index) => (new Date(item.start_date).getTime() >= new Date(filterDate.start_date).getTime() && new Date(item.end_date).getTime() <= new Date(filterDate.end_date).getTime()));

const personCount = filteredItems.length;

console.log(`Person count >>>>>>> ${personCount}`);
```